# Numbers along with name of branch in Github

Tags: git, github

I am using github to maintain my Code.

When i am on GitShell on Command Prompt. I could see some numbers along with branch name like this "+2 ~0 -0" after i added submodule

C:\Users\DELL\Documents\FacebookLogin [master +2 ~0 -0]>.

What are these numbers refer to "master +2 ~0 -0".

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 new files added (+2) which have not been added to the staging area yet(untracked files). The next ~0 is to indicate you have not modified a file(this will change to ~1 if you modify/update a file). Not sure what the next -0 is for.

Comment: The third field indicates the number of deleted files.